# steepness rate of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

if we have a sequence of random variables $X_n\to 0$ a.s. (but we have no idea how fast), can we always build a sequence $a_n\to\infty$ such that $a_nX_n\to 0$ still? If not what is a counterexample.

I tried using $a_n:=\frac{1}{\sup\{\omega: X_n(\omega)^{2}\}}$ but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

How about if $X_n \sim \frac 1{\log n} \to 0$  But $nX_n \sim \frac n{\log n} \to \infty$.  Presumably $a_n \ge n$ because you are picking them.

Comment: well the counterexample would have to be the r.v's $X_n$ such that no sequence $a_n$ exists?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can I choose the $X_n$?  If so, I choose them as $\frac 1{\log n}$ and there is no sequence because any subsequence will increase at least as fast as $\frac n{\log n}$.  I was assuming I got to choose the range of the $X_n$, but that each was random within the range.  Then  I can't prove there is no convergent subsequence, but I can show it has probability $0$.  That should be clear.

Comment: No you cannot choose the $X_n$, it is given that $X_n\to 0$. I am saying given this information. Can we always produce a sequence of real numbers such that $a_n\to\infty$ while $a_nX_n\to 0$.

Comment: IF no such sequence of $a_n$ is possible, I would like to know what sequence of $X_n$ will do the trick.

Comment: My $X_n$ go to zero.  They just go slowly enough that when multiplied by $n$ they increase.

Comment: so the $a_n$ should be related to the $X_n$ somehow (similar to my attempt)

Comment: If each $X_n$ is drawn from a uniform distribution from $0$ to $\log n$, almost surely there will be no sequence of $a_n$s that will work.  Of course, it is possible, because all the randoms could be very small, but the probability goes to zero.  That is what you are missing.

Comment: $a_n=\log(n)^{1/2}$ works. this blows up while $a_nX_n=\frac{1}{\log(n)^{1/2}}$ goes to 0